# Here Maps Returning geo coordinates in wrong state

Tags: geolocation, here-api

We are using the geocoder api with Here maps. This works most of the time but we have a few addresses that are returning back with geo location information from the wrong state.

A specific example is: https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=myAppId&app_code=myAppCode&searchtext=98+SW+ASH+LANE+TRENTON+MO

We are passing in 'MO' at the end of the search text as we know the location is in Missouri. However, we are getting back a result from Maine.

Result String:

```
{"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2019-01-        
29T21:37:09.728+0000"},"View":                
[{"_type":"SearchResultsViewType","ViewId":0,"Result": 
[{"Relevance":0.75,"MatchLevel":"houseNumber","MatchQuality": 
{"City":1.0,"Street": 
[1.0],"HouseNumber":1.0},"MatchType":"interpolated","Location": 
[enter image description here][1]{"LocationId":"NT_sIneFT1KLOf1QLeV9a6rED_5gD","LocationType":"point","DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":44.4731092,"Longitude":-68.2688426},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":44.4732204,"Longitude":-68.2689496}],"MapView":{"TopLeft":{"Latitude":44.4742333,"Longitude":-68.2704179},"BottomRight":{"Latitude":44.471985,"Longitude":-68.2672672}},"Address":{"Label":"98 Ash Ln, Lamoine, ME 04605, United States","Country":"USA","State":"ME","County":"Hancock","City":"Lamoine","Street":"Ash Ln","HouseNumber":"98","PostalCode":"04605","AdditionalData":[{"value":"United States","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"Maine","key":"StateName"},{"value":"Hancock","key":"CountyName"},{"value":"N","key":"PostalCodeType"}]}}}]}]}}
```

We discovered if we do a search for 98 SW ASH LANE, trenton, MO using wego.here.com it bring up several possible locations that match this address, one of which is the Maine address (wrong) and another is the Missouri address (correct). (see image)

If I specify at the end of my search string 'MO' for Missouri, why is it returning back a result in Maine? Better yet, if I specify a state, why is it returning back multiple results in other states and how do I force it to return back from the state I specified?

Answer (score 0):

You may use instead the Places autosuggest API:

```
https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id=XXXX&app_code=YYYY&at=48.57344807876947%2C2.3109863281250114&q=98%20SW%20ASH%20LANE%20TRENTON%20MO
```

User's guide can be found : [there](http://documentation.developer.here.com/pdf/places_pub/2.69.0/Places%20(Search)%20API%20Public%20v2.69.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not quite sure that's what we're looking for. All we want to do is geo code an address. No user interface / auto complete. Just want the geo coordinates for a given address.